# Social bar failing to reload in my Rails 4.2.6 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, heroku

I have a Rails 4.2.6 hosted at Heroku. This is the [link](http://portaldemocracia.herokuapp.com/) to it.

It happens that I am facing a very curious issue and maybe someone here may help me to solve it.

My application has a social bar with Twitter, LinkedIn and Facebook share buttons. When I first navigate to the homepage, these buttons load perfectly. It will be like in this image:

[image]

But if I navigate to another page, say [this](http://portaldemocracia.herokuapp.com/forum), and navigate back to the homepage, these buttons won't reload.

[image]

I really don't know what is happening and any help will be appreciated.

Here are some elements which may be useful.

**config/routes.rb**:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'site#index'
  get '/forum',       to: 'site#forum',       as: :forum_disqus
  get '/deputados',   to: 'site#deputados',   as: :lista_deputados
  get '/senadores',   to: 'site#senadores',   as: :lista_senadores
  get '/mensagem',    to: 'site#mensagem',    as: :envio_mensagens
end
```

**app/views/site/index.html.erb**:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="well well-sm news-box clearfix">
      <%= render 'news' %>
    </div>
    <div class="well well-sm editorial-box">
      <%= render 'editorial' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="well well-sm social-buttons clearfix">
      <%= render 'social' %>
    </div>
    <div class="well well-sm twitter-box">
      <%= render 'twitter_camara' %>
    </div>
    <div class="well well-sm twitter-box">
       <%= render 'twitter_senado' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app/views/site/_social.html.erb**:

```
<div class="botao-twitter">
  <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://portaldemocracia.herokuapp.com/" data-via="edvaldoajunior" data-lang="pt" data-size="large" data-hashtags="PortalDemocracia">Tweetar</a>
  <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
</div>
<div class="botao-linkedin">
  <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: pt_BR</script>
  <script type="IN/Share" data-url="http://portaldemocracia.herokuapp.com/" data-counter="right"></script>
</div>
<div class="botao-facebook">
  <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://portaldemocracia.herokuapp.com/" data-layout="box_count"></div>
</div>
<div class="botao-facebook">
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/portaldemocracia" data-width="90" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
</div>
```

This is the code related with Facebook API loading, in my **app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**, and it is the only part of my code related with the social bar in this file.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=1623539961200011";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning pops up in the console: `duplicate in.js loaded, any parameters will be ignored`

It looks like the LinkedIn script is getting loaded again when you return to the homepage. Does trying one of the fixes mentioned in [this answer to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32136567/1759738) fix the issue?

Comment: This helped, but only with LinkedIn button. The other aren't loading. Do you know some way to invalidate the other scripts as **delete IN;** of the answer you indicated me invalidates the linkedin script?

Comment: Is there extra code somewhere loading the Facebook scripts? Also, do you have some shared header in your application where you could place the <script> tags? That way you could guarantee that the scripts would only be loaded once (and not every time you switch tabs).

Comment: There is just the code to load Facebook API. This code is in my **app/views/layouts/application.html.erb** exactly for this reason, to be loaded once. The area I'm having problems with appears just at **app/views/site/index.html.erb** and there would be no sense in moving it to other place.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you post what you have in your `application.html.erb` related to that script loading? Also, it might make sense to move the twitter script into that block.

Comment: It makes no sense to move the twitter script to somewhere else, because it displays the button where it is.