# LinkedIn link not always displayed on Angularjs website

Tags: html, angularjs, linkedin-api

I am working on a not for profit website in Angularjs and when i add the LinkedIn and Facebook share buttons, the Facebook button is always displayed but the linkedIn button is only displayed on initial load only.
When I go to mcwn.org the buttons are displayed. When i click through the tab buttons at the top and then go back to the home page by clinking on the website logo at the top the LinkedIn button is not displayed.

Anyone with ideas? this is very frustrating.
Thanks

Comment: I go to mcwn.org and i have not seen the linkedIn link ...
Sorry now it's working on my laptop i think it's function great .

Comment: your web site think doesn't work on IE-11 Windows Seven

Comment: I think this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560907/loading-mulitple-linkedin-share-buttons-dynamically-and-asynchronously   general search : https://www.google.com/search?q=duplicate+in.js+loaded%2C+any+parameters+will+be+ignored&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab

Comment: Thank you for the input, I have changed the active links to plain links that are images with anchor tag around each. Keeping it simple works better.

Comment: This working ? :)

Comment: The site is working, i have gone to a more simpler link. by just using html <a> tag to the site. instead of using js link generated by FB or linkedin. This has less functionality and with a single page app less issues.

Comment: Thx for your reply :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @pascal-sanchez in comment is saying, that linkedin js file is loading twice in your website .

In Console log you can find such error.

"duplicate in.js loaded, any parameters will be ignored"

---

If we will see "pure page code", we will find linkedin file just once. It tells us that second file is written asynchronously to header part. Probably it provokes errors on loading. You can try change this line:

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
```

to this

```
<script>
if (typeof (IN) !== 'undefined') {
  // IN.parse(); // old but still supports
  IN.init();  // reinitiating linkedin button  
} else {
  $.getScript("http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js");
}   
</script>
```

This script will check if likedin already initiated and loaded, if not it will initiate it.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I have changed the active links to plain links that are images with anchor tag around each. Keeping it simple works better. I also saw the "duplicate load" and was able to find how to solve. I will check you code and mark as solution if it works to fix the